# Adding class on i+3 type iteration

Tags: php, html, arrays

I am pulling some info from array, and I'm wrapping it in wrapper so that every 6 items are in a wrapper. This gives me some number of wrappers. Now I need to add classes that repeat based on `i+3` iteration. So I need to have something like this:

```
<div class="results_wrapper title1"></div>
<div class="results_wrapper title2"></div>
<div class="results_wrapper title3"></div>
<div class="results_wrapper title1"></div>
<div class="results_wrapper title2"></div>
<div class="results_wrapper title3"></div>
<div class="results_wrapper title1"></div>
<div class="results_wrapper title2"></div>
<div class="results_wrapper title3"></div>
<div class="results_wrapper title1"></div>
<div class="results_wrapper title2"></div>
<div class="results_wrapper title3"></div>
<div class="results_wrapper title1"></div>
<div class="results_wrapper title2"></div>
<div class="results_wrapper title3"></div>
```

My current code is (incomplete):

```
foreach ($tables_completed[$content_count]['table_match'] as $tbm_k => $tbm_v) {
    $wrap_count = 1;
    $swipe_title = '';
    array_shift($tbm_v);
    foreach ($tbm_v as $ind_match_k => $ind_match_v) {
        if( $wrap_count % 6 == 1 ){
            if ($wrap_count) {
                $swipe_title = 'total';
            } elseif($wrap_count){
                $swipe_title = 'hemma';
            } else{
                $swipe_title = 'borta';
            }
            $out .= '<div class="results_wrapper'.$swipe_title.'" data-title="'.ucfirst($swipe_title).'">';
        }
        $out .= '<span>'.$ind_match_v.'</span>';
        if( $wrap_count % 6 == 0){
            $out .= '</div>';
        }
        $wrap_count++;
    }

}
```

The `$tables_completed` has entries like this:

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [table_match] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => 2
                            [2] => 2
                            [3] => 0
                            [4] => 0
                            [6] => 9
                            [7] => 6
                            [8] => 1
                            [9] => 1
                            [10] => 0
                            [11] => 0
                            [13] => 5
                            [14] => 3
                            [15] => 1
                            [16] => 1
                            [17] => 0
                            [18] => 0
                            [20] => 4
                            [21] => 3
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => 3
                            [2] => 2
                            [3] => 0
                            [4] => 1
                            [6] => 3
                            [7] => 6
                            [8] => 2
                            [9] => 1
                            [10] => 0
                            [11] => 1
                            [13] => 0
                            [14] => 3
                            [15] => 1
                            [16] => 1
                            [17] => 0
                            [18] => 0
                            [20] => 3
                            [21] => 3
                        )
```

Wrapping works perfectly, I get 6 numbers wrapped for each entry, but I need to add repeating classes to them, and my head is just empty.

## EDIT

So in theory this should work:

```
<?php

$i = 1;

for( $i; $i < 14; $i++ ) {
    if( ($i-2/3) % 3 == 0 ){
        print_r('TRUE for '.$i."\r\n");
    } else {
        print_r('false for '.$i."\r\n");
    }   
}
```

So for `1, 4, 7, 10, 13, ...` the check should be

```
($i-2/3) % 3 == 0
```

Because the nth term of that sequence is:

```
a_n = 3n-2; n= 1, 2, 3, ...
```

Likewise for `2, 5, 8, 11, 14, ...` the formula for the nth term is

```
a_n = 3n-1; n= 1, 2, 3, ...
```

That is,

```
($i-1/3) % 3 == 0
```

But when I try with

```
if( $wrap_count % 6 == 1 ){
    if ( ($wrap_count-2/3) % 3 == 0 ) {
        $swipe_title = 'total';
    } elseif( ($wrap_count-1/3) % 3 == 0){
        $swipe_title = 'hemma';
    } else{
        $swipe_title = 'borta';
    }
    if ($wrap_count % 18 == 1) {
        $out .= '<div class="single_match_wrapper"><div class="results_wrapper ' .$swipe_title.'" data-title="'.ucfirst($swipe_title).'">';
    } else{
        $out .= '<div class="results_wrapper '.$swipe_title.'" data-title="'.ucfirst($swipe_title).'">';
    }
}
```

I only get the `total` out. I added a wrapper around every 3 smaller wrappers so that it looks like

```
<div class="single_match_wrapper">
    <div class="results_wrapper total" data-title="Total">
        <span>2</span><span>2</span><span>0</span><span>0</span><span>9</span><span>6</span>
    </div>
    <div class="results_wrapper total" data-title="Total">
        <span>1</span><span>1</span><span>0</span><span>0</span><span>5</span><span>3</span>
    </div>
    <div class="results_wrapper total" data-title="Total">
        <span>1</span><span>1</span><span>0</span><span>0</span><span>4</span><span>3</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="single_match_wrapper"></div>
```

The math is sound, but the programming logic is obviously faulty somewhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I added

```
data-num="'.$wrap_count.'"
```

To my

```
$out .= '<div class="results_wrapper '.$swipe_title.'" data-title="'.ucfirst($swipe_title).'">';
```

And I always got `1, 7, 13`. Which makes sense since I want to wrap 6 of them.

So I just added:

```
if ( $wrap_count == 1 ) {
    $swipe_title = 'total';
}

if ( $wrap_count == 7 ){
    $swipe_title = 'hemma';
}

if ( $wrap_count == 13 ) {
    $swipe_title = 'borta';
}
```

I need to check it for other results, but this should work.